# Log4j2/Slf4j and Java 11

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, slf4j, java-11

I'm currently trying to build an app with log4j/slf4j and java 11 but I'm facing this problem at runtime:

```
2018-12-10 22:09:27,225 main INFO Cannot initialize scripting support because this JRE does not support it. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/script/ScriptEngineManager
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core@2.11.1/org.apache.logging.log4j.core.script.ScriptManager.<init>(ScriptManager.java:69)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core@2.11.1/org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:216)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core@2.11.1/org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:250)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core@2.11.1/org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:547)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core@2.11.1/org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:619)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core@2.11.1/org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:636)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core@2.11.1/org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:231)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core@2.11.1/org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:153)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core@2.11.1/org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j/org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j/org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.slf4j@2.11.1/org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j/org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.slf4j@2.11.1/org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.slf4j/org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:355)
    at org.slf4j/org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:380)
    at fr.mrcraftcod.nameascreated/fr.mrcraftcod.nameascreated.NameAsCreated.<clinit>(NameAsCreated.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.script.ScriptEngineManager
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 17 more
```

The code that is at the origin of this is the initialization of my logger:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NameAsCreated.class);
```

I have dependencies on:

- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.11.1
- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.11.1
- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j18-impl:2.11.1
- A maven project that depends on org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.8.0-beta2

I'm on OSX Mojave with Java version:

```
openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11+28-201810021910)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11+28-201810021910, mixed mode)
```

Does someone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong and how I can solve this?

Comment: Possibly related to https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/335

Comment: I usually use Logback for the logger implementation: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic. I don't have any further idea.

Comment: @TomG Read the non-goals from the same link  *This deprecation does not affect, in any way, the javax.script API.*

Comment: Can you share how you are building and running the app? Is it modular or not? If possible any frameworks used or not?

Comment: Does org.apache.logging.log4j depend on java.scripting? If so then it must be missing `requires  java.scripting` from its module declaration. If it claims that it's an optional dependency then the issue is that nobody` requires  java.scripting` so this module will not be resolved. You should be able to work around it with `--add-modules java.scripting`. You won't have this issue with applications on the class path because  java.scripting will be resolved by default in that case.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the comments.

I didn't try every answer but the one of @AlanBateman did work by just adding the require in the module-info. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Log4j documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html):

> Log4j provides support for JSR 223 scripting languages to be used in some of its components.

and as said in the comments by `Alan Bateman` from Java 9 you have to add explicitly the java scripting module either with `--add-modules java.scripting` or in `module-info.java`.

Note also that the module `jdk.scripting.nashorn` is [deprecated in Java 11](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/335) and will be removed in a future release.

Comment: I should also add that this is an informational message and the only impact will be this message and that scripts in the configuration are not supported.

Comment: So that I'm understanding correctly, log4j2 won't run without this error unless you add this? If so, does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to log4j2 version 2.17.2 or higher.

Comment: Take the [tour] and visit the [help]. In my opinion, your "answer" is really a comment - since it seems that you are not sure as to whether upgrading "log4j2" will solve the problem. I believe you should adhere to the rules of SO which means that you should not post a comment as an answer merely because you don't yet have enough reputation to comment.