# Running Log4j2 with Java 11 and Spring Boot causes NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, nullpointerexception, log4j

When my Spring Boot application starts up and initializes my Log4j2 logger in Java 11, I get the following exception:

```
2021-10-08 11:20:29,949 main INFO Cannot initialize scripting support because this JRE does not support it. java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.toString()" because the return value of "javax.script.ScriptEngine.get(String)" is null
at org.luaj.vm2.script.LuaScriptEngineFactory.getParameter(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.script.ScriptManager.<init>(ScriptManager.java:84)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:219)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:287)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:627)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:700)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfigLocation(LoggerContext.java:685)
```

There was another answer for the same problem a few years ago here: [Log4j2/Slf4j and Java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53714010/log4j2-slf4j-and-java-11)

However this answer from a few years ago, did not give me the steps I needed to figure out how to remove this. There was a discussion that it was an OpenJDK issue, and that it should be fixed now, but I am still struggling with this.

Does anyone understand this issue a bit more, why it only happens with Spring Boot, and what I can do to get rid of it in a clean way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is different from the [question you cite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53714010/log4j2-slf4j-and-java-11). Your classpath must contain the [`luaj-jse`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.luaj/luaj-jse/3.0.1) scripting engine, which has a bug:

```java
    public Object getParameter(String key) {
        return getScriptEngine().get(key).toString();
    }
```

When `getParameter` is called with a missing key (like *"THREADING"*), this causes a `NullPointerException`.

You should [report this bug](https://github.com/luaj/luaj/issues) to LuaJ. In the meantime you can either ignore the error or remove `luaj-jse` from your dependencies.

Comment: That was it! Thank you!